# Counting unread messages or annoucements for a given user

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, count

I'm working on a simple internal messaging/annoucement system to use on a company portal/website. I would like to get the count of unread messages or annoucements for a given user. Because the Messages Details table contains more information than just "Seen/Unread" a simple left join statement does not work. I have created a statement that returns the Unread number, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to achive the same result.

The output is:

| Unread |
| --- |
| 2 |

Example Table Structures

Table "**Messages**":

| Id | Target | Target_Value | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User | User1 | Message 1 |
| 2 | User | User1 | Message 2 |
| 3 | User | User1 | Message 3 |
| 4 | Group | Managers | Annoucement 1 |
| 5 | User | User2 | Message 4 |

Table "**Messages_Details**":

| Id | Type | Value | User_Id | IDKEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tag | Important | User1 | 1 |
| 2 | Tag | Tag1 | User2 | 1 |
| 3 | Seen | 1 | User1 | 1 |
| 4 | Seen | 1 | User1 | 4 |
| 5 | Tag | Tag2 | User1 | 2 |

Table "**Users**":

| Id | User_Id | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | Managers |
| 2 | User2 | Sales |
| 3 | User3 | XYZ |
| 4 | User4 | Admin |

My working query:

```
WITH DataList AS (
    SELECT M.Id as Message,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM Messages_Details D
            WHERE D.IDKEY = M.Id 
              AND D.Type='Seen' AND D.Value=1 
              AND D.User_Id='User1') AS Seen
    FROM Messages M
    WHERE (M.Target='User' AND M.Target_Value='User1') 
       OR (M.Target='Group' AND M.Target_Value ='Managers')
) 
SELECT (COUNT(Message)-SUM(Seen)) AS Unread
FROM DataList;
```

I tried to create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bf536/5/0) but I wasn't able to test the full query.

Any advice or help is appreciated!

Comment: Sure, I just updated the post, thanks

Comment: If you're output is 2, it's enough to use Messages_Details table and count the amount of seen messages through aggregation. Is this what you want?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you actually using? Your SQLFiddle says 5.6, but no-one should be runing 5.6 in 2023...

Comment: I'm using MariaDB 10

Comment: @lemon, could you explain or provide an example? I'm still somewhat new to mysql. Btw, the code does work properly on the site, I'm just trying to understand mysql statements better.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was flagged as a duplicate question and the solution on the page is quite different from my situation where I have data from two tables.